# Comparing a user input to a list in order to call a function

Tags: python

I am currently trying to create what I had thought would be a simple measurement conversion program, I wanted to include the measurements: MM, CM, M and inches. However I have run into a snag. I need the program to be able to read a user input and compare the input to a list of acceptable words (measurementLst) in order to decide which conversion function to run, but when I run the program and input mm then cm along with the mm value, the function is not called I would love if anybody could help me shed some light on this? The issue occurs on line 14 many thanks! (Be nice I am new to python) :3

```
measurementLst = ["cm", "centimetres", "inch", "inches", "metres", "m", "metre", "mm", "millimetres"]


# Millimetres to Centimetres conversion subroutine
def mmtocm():
    conversionMMtoCM = storedVal / 10
    print("CM: ", conversionMMtoCM)


# User decides conversion to use for the program
storedStr1 = input("Which measurement would you like to convert from: mm, cm, inch or m? ")
storedStr2 = input("Which measurement would you like to convert to: mm, cm, inch or m? ")
storedVal = int(input("What is the value of your measurement? "))
if storedStr2.casefold() in measurementLst[0][1] and storedStr1.casefold() in measurementLst[7][8]:
    mmtocm()
~~~~
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you get an error message, please include it in your post. It could help the readers better understand the specific problem you got stuck with and also it could help others find your post and learn from it.

Comment: Issue is `measurementLst[0][1]` is the second letter of the 0-th word or character 'm' and `measurementLst[7][8]` is letter index of 7th word.  Try: `if storedStr2.casefold() in measurementLst[0] and storedStr1.casefold() in measurementLst[7]:`

Comment: You confused access by index, and range selection. Try to print `measurementLst[0][1]` and `measurementLst[7][8]`. You'll fine that `measurementLst[0][1]` is second letter of first word, while you probably meant `measurementLst[0:2]` which would be a range `["cm", "centimetres"]`

Comment: This approach is way more work than needed. You can put all your conversions into a data structure keyed by tuples like ("cm", "feet") and then have the values be the ratio between the two units.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75977998/comparing-a-user-input-to-a-list-in-order-to-call-a-function/75978289#comment134004446_75977998) from [Alexey Larionov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8564999/alexey-larionov)

```
if storedStr2.casefold() in measurementLst[0:1] and storedStr1.casefold() in measurementLst[7:8]:
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you can't use `measurementLst[0][1]` because it represents to access the element at index 1 of the string at index 0 in the list measurementLst. However, since `measurementLst` is a list of strings, and not a list of lists, it would be an error.
You can add a detailed `if` statement:

```
if storedStr1.casefold() in measurementLst:
    if storedStr1.casefold() == "mm" or storedStr1.casefold() == "millimetres":
        if storedStr2.casefold() == "cm" or storedStr2.casefold() == "centimetres":
            mmtocm(storedVal)
        else:
            print("Invalid input for conversion from mm to cm.")
# Add more conditions..
else:
    print("Invalid measurement.")
```

Though it's more complicated, but it should work now.

Comment: It will be an "error" in the sense that it's incorrect, but it won't throw an exception.`measurementLst[0][1]` will be `'m'`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't honestly complete your application like that. In your current variant you would have to create separate function for all pairs of units. But you can do simpler - convert to some unified unit (I convert into meters), then from meters convert to your destination units. That way, you only need to provide conversion functions from any to meters, and from meters to any, instead of every single pair of units.

```
measurementLst = ["cm", "centimetres", "inch", "inches", "metres", "m", "metre", "mm", "millimetres"]

convertersToMeters = {}
convertersToMeters["cm"] = convertersToMeters["centimetres"] = lambda cm: cm/100
convertersToMeters["m"] = convertersToMeters["metres"] = convertersToMeters["metre"] = lambda m: m
convertersToMeters["mm"] = convertersToMeters["millimetres"] = lambda mm: mm/1000
convertersToMeters["inch"] = lambda inch: inch*0.0254

convertersFromMeters = {}
convertersFromMeters["cm"] = convertersFromMeters["centimetres"] = lambda m: m*100
convertersFromMeters["m"] = convertersFromMeters["metres"] = convertersFromMeters["metre"] = lambda m: m
convertersFromMeters["mm"] = convertersFromMeters["millimetres"] = lambda m: m*1000
convertersFromMeters["inch"] = lambda inch: inch*39.37

convertFrom = input("Convert from: mm, cm, inch or m? ")
fromFunc = convertersToMeters.get(convertFrom)
if fromFunc is None:
  print("Conversion from", convertFrom, "is not   supported") 
  exit()
convertTo = input("Convert to: mm, cm, inch or m? ")
toFunc = convertersFromMeters.get(convertTo)
if toFunc is None:
  print("Conversion to", convertTo, "is not supported")
  exit()
storedVal = float(input("What is the value of your measurement? "))

# from initial unit -> meters, from meters to destination unit
convertedValue = toFunc(fromFunc(storedVal)) 
print(storedVal, convertFrom, " -> ", convertedValue, convertTo)
```